# Eliminating vertical/horizontal gaps in a seamless grid of images

Tags: css, grid, whitespace, vertical-alignment, alignment

I am having some trouble creating a seamless photo grid. I have searched the internet for quite a while, and I can't find any solutions.

I have a grid of images that are all square and all the same size. I have eliminated gaps that occur on every row by adding `img { vertical-align: middle; }`

Now I need to eliminate the vertical white space that occurs in each column.

[Here is the site I am working on](http://test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/debug/index.php)

[Here is a screenshot of the site I am working on](http://cl.ly/2p1b302M203W3r1X052S)

You can see there is about 2-3px of white space the the left and right of the images. I have tried `margin:0` and `padding:0` on just about everything I can think of.

I have the grid set up using `display:inline-block`. I need to keep this. I don't want to use floats.

My HTML is pretty simple:

```
<ul><li><a href="#"><img src="0.jpg" /></a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank so much for the quickest response I've ever seen at stackoverflow.

I made a silly mistake though. Since I am using `inline-block` I forgot that it accounts for whitespace in the HTML. I removed all of the whitespace, and now it seems to work.

@MartinCortez's answers seems to work as well, if I didn't want to fool with whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Do this to eliminate the vertical white-space that appears in each column:

```
#photos li img { width: 102% }
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove width columns.css line 101

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use floats?  Here's what I suggest:

```
ul { overflow: auto; width: XXXpx; }

li {
  float: left;
  width: XXXpx;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
}



<ul>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late now however I thought I'd share what I would do, as others may find it useful.

As @davecave said it's a whitespace issue but removing the whitespace in the HTML isn't always ideal.

On the containing element I normally do:

```
#container {
    letter-spacing: -4px;
    word-spacing: -4px; 
}
```

and on the items that are inline-block reset the values:

```
.item {
    letter-spacing:0;
    word-spacing:0;
}
```